# Tableaux switching

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, young-tableaux

I'm reading the article [Tableau Switching: Algorithms and Applications](https://doi.org/10.1006/jcta.1996.0086) by Benkart, Sottile, and Stroomer. Do you know if there are any articles or books that talk more about the properties of tableau switching further than Theorem 2.2, 2.3 and 3.1? Or give another point of view for tableau switching?

Comment: https://hal.inria.fr › documentPDF

A variation on the tableau switching and a Pak-Vallejo's conjecture - HAL-Inria by Olga Azenhas (and other papers by same author)

Comment: Thank you so much. I will look at this!